# A question about complex plane algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-curves, plane-geometry

I would like to ask a question about plane projective curves. Let $C\subset{\mathbb P}_2={\mathbb P}(V)$ be a plane curve of degree $n\geq 3$. Then we have a non splitted exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow{\mathcal O}_C(-n)\longrightarrow\Omega_{{\mathbb P}_2|C}\longrightarrow\omega_C={\mathcal O}_C(n-3)\longrightarrow 0,$$
hence an element $\sigma$ of $H^1({\mathcal O}_C(3-2n))$. By using the exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow{\mathcal O}_{{\mathbb P}_2}(-n)\longrightarrow{\mathcal O}_{{\mathbb P}_2}\longrightarrow{\mathcal O}_C\longrightarrow 0$$
we get an inclusion
$$H^1({\mathcal O}_C(3-2n))\ \subset\ H^2({\mathcal O}_{{\mathbb P}_2}(3-3n))\ =\ S^{3n-6}V \ . $$
Hence $\sigma$ corresponds to a curve of degree $3n-6$ in the dual projective plane ${\mathbb P}_2^*$.

My question is : what is this curve ? (or did I a mistake somewhere ?).

Comment: You might check Dolgachev's book on classical algebraic geometry.  He describes a number of remarkable operations on plane curves.

Comment: I spoke today with Fedorchuk, who is an expert.  He says that probably this is not in Dolgachev's book (at least not directly).  Rather, this is the associated curve of Isaev (studied by Alper-Isaev, and most recently by Fedorchuk).

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you very much for these references.